# How does the new Formula Editor work in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word

In my Office 365 subscription I recently got an update which made my formulas in Word look like this:

[image: Weird Word formula representation]

Firstly, I have those blue marks that surround the formula. Although they disappear as soon as I print or export the document, they look ugly while editing. Secondly, I was used to type e. g. `1/3`, then hit Space and Word would convert what I just typed in professional representation. Now, it doesn't and I have to click the arrow next to the formula and select 'Convert all to professional'. This is annoying as I would prefer to leave my hands on the keyboard.

Does anyone know how to fix those issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are running Office 365 version 1807 Build(10325.20082) the problem is being caused by a bug in that version, which has been reported.

The blue marks are Design Mode indicators and you can go to the Developer Tab and reset the Design Mode toggle switch. However, I don't know if that will correct the other issue you are having with the "Convert to Professional".

The other alternative you have is to revert to the earlier build of Office365. The procedure for doing that is here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic

Comment: Switching design mode off actually did fix the conversion as well. Thanks :)